# laravel 5 : Routes Authentication error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to protect the index page from direct access. And also want to restrict direct access for `/` .

The problem is when i enter the correct credentials for login it throws and error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:`.
And that error comes up when i enter the wrong credentials for login also.

My routes.php code is

```
Route::get('index', array(
'before' => 'auth',
function(){
    return view('login');
}));
Route::get('/login', function(){
    return view('login');
});
Route::post('/login',function(){
    $cred = Input::only('username','password');
    if(Auth::attempt($cred)){
        return Redirect::intended('index');
    };
    return Redirect::to('/login');
});
Route::get('/logout', function(){
    Auth::logout();
    return view('logout');
});
Route::get('/register', function(){
    return view('register');
});
Route::post('/register',function(){

    $user = new \App\User;
    $user->username = input::get('username');
    $user->email  = input::get('email');
    $user->password = Hash::make(input::get('username'));
    $user->designation = input::get('designation');
    $user->save();
    $theEmail = Input::get('username');
    return view('thanks')->with('theEmail',$theEmail);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel 5,

```
['before' => 'auth']
```

is deprecated. But instead, you should use

```
['middleware' => 'auth']
```

[For more information about middleware in laravel click here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply but also i think i  have a bug here.
`Route::post('/login',function(){`

Answer (score 0):

MethodNotAllowedHttpException shows up when you are posting to a get route from your form, or vice versa. Could you check that your login form's method is set to POST.